# With the ACE Editor, how can I unbind an event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, ace-editor

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Embedding---API

```
editor.session.on('change', callback);
```

is how you bind an event to "change". But how do I unbind it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `removeListener` to remove a specific callback.

```
editor.session.removeListener('change', callback);
```

or a shorter version

```
editor.session.off('change', callback);
```

Use `removeAllListeners` to remove all callbacks.

```
editor.session.removeAllListeners('change');
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting specifically that `editor.session.off('change')` (without the callback, will not work.

Comment: I had an issue with `editor.session.removeAllListeners('change');`. The editor stopped rendering changes as if an internal change event was being used to refresh the content. The targeted version worked fine though.