# Remove Listner from Monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

After attaching any callback to `editor.onDidChangeModelContent(event)` to a Monaco instance, how do I remove (or unbind) this function?

The ACE editor, for example, provides the [function `removeListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157435/with-the-ace-editor-how-can-i-unbind-an-event) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6):

Stating the Monaco documentation, all [event functions return an `IDisposable` object](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.icodeeditor.html#ondidchangemodelcontent). This interface defines a [function called `dispose`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.idisposable.html#dispose). I'd suggest calling this function when attempting to "unbind" a listener, e.g.:

```js
var disposable = editor.onDidChangeModelContent (function (event) {});
// ...
disposable.dispose ();
```